# How to text a download link to iPhone from App promo site?

Tags: iphone, ios, promotions

I want to make a "Get the app" link to text a download link to users iPhones.
Is there any service which do that for you easily?

You can see the examples from http://piictu.com/.

Comment: I guess you'll need to fins a service that sends free text messages to phones...
Still I would suggest you simple add a qrcode link in your page, which the user can scan with any of the free qrcode reading scanners on the App Store and it would actually link to your app in the app store...

Comment: hmm, I thought there would be services do that for you, but they all might just handle them by them self.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://linksense.io and http://linktexting.com without having to code anything.

LinkSense.io will make a link that detects the device type and sends the user to the right store.

LinkTexting.com will allow you to sign up for Twilio and/or connect your Twilio account to make an embedded SMS form.